# angular directive window event listener

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, event-handling

I am new to angularJS, and do not fully understand event listeners and memory shizzle. So what happends when I have a directive, used on multiple elements, that is setting a window resize eventlistener. When this directive is set on 20 elements is the window event:

1. set 20 times
2. set once because the function allready excists.
3. set as many times you want, as long it doesn't occur a million
   times.....

I am affraid that a lot of memory is used, and I might want to use it for changing image src depending on the window viewport....

```
angular.module('log').directive(
    "log",['$window', '$http', function($window, $http) {

        return ({
            link: function link( $scope, element, attributes ) {
                var logFunc = function logFunc() {
                    console.log(
                          'I want to change the src attribute,'
                        + ' depending on viewport, by using'
                        + ' element.src = attributes.src1024'
                    );
                };

                angular.element($window).bind('resize', logFunc);
            }
        });
    }]
);

<img src="" log data-src1024="img/1024/some-image.jpg" />
<img src="" log data-src1024="img/1024/some-image.jpg" />
<img src="" log data-src1024="img/1024/some-image.jpg" />
<img src="" log data-src1024="img/1024/some-image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Multiple identical event listeners

If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and since the duplicates are discarded, they do not need to be removed manually with the removeEventListener method.

Comment: Except that they aren't identical, since the "logFunc" method is on a different object. I'm having the same issue as the OP and it causes multiple listeners.
Issue that I'm having is that $(window).off is not working either...